# How to avoid overloading of application main form by multi tabs webbrowser?

Tags: browser, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser

I'm using multiple `TCppWebBrowser`s on main form, and when I start the application all tabs from last internet session are recovered. But this makes the main form of application to overload much. My question is how can I avoid overloading of main form?

I tried myself to achieve it but had no success. I used `TThread` class from C++ Builder and tried to start navigation from there, but unsuccessful, main form still overloading. I also tried `CreateThread()` - same thing.

I have found:

[WebBrowser Control (MFC) created in seperate thread working in Windows 7 and Vista, but Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699633/webbrowser-control-mfc-created-in-seperate-thread-working-in-windows-7-and-vist)

But I do not understand this very well.

Please somebody tell me how to solve my question in C++ Builder!

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I'd leave the threads aside and would try loading one page after another. It's easier. All you have to do is to not load the content of all `TCppWebBrowsers`at once, instead start by loading only the first (visible to the user) then load the others one by one.

Load a tab when one of the following happens:

- the user activates a tab - you should definitely load this page immediately
- the application is idle and no other tab is loading - load the next one

Do this until all tabs are loaded.

Of course you need to be able to somehow influence the "session recovering mechanism" to implement this delay-loading. But if you would be able to add threads then you should also be able to just load the tabs one by one. This will spread the load over a longer time and should prevent overloading your app at startup.